# Is it possible to create a CosmosDB with ARM templates?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to create an ARM template that provisions a CosmosDB instance, the only documentation I've found however is for DocumentDB which I'm aware is what Cosmos used to be called. If I provision a DocumentDB cluster will that create a CosmosDB instance? If not Does anybody have any experience of provisioning a CosmosDB with an ARM template and if so, is there any reference material I can read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, those are the same. Just use this [examples repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates). You are looking for any examples with `documentdb` or `cosmosdb` in the name.

Alternatively you can créate a CosmosDB instance in the portal and look at the template that is being used to créate it (under deployments in the resource group where you deployed it).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! :)